# Other users are logged in (Ubuntu)

Tags: 20.04, users

My `w` shows the followingn results:

```
linux@dell:~$ w
14:56:46 up 15 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.16, 0.27, 0.31
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
linux    tty7     :0               14:41   15:51  22.09s  0.03s /usr/libexec/gnome-session-bina

linux@dell:~$ ps -ef | grep "user"
oracle       940       1  0 14:40 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
oracle      1029     940  0 14:40 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1001/gvfs -f
linux       1532       1  0 14:41 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
linux       1566    1532  0 14:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs -f
linux       1676    1667  0 14:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/defaults/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 11 --address=unix:path=/run/user/1000/at-spi/bus_0
linux       1705    1532  0 14:41 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent -D -a /run/user/1000/openssh_agent
root        1847    1842  0 14:41 ?        00:00:00 fusermount3 -o rw,nosuid,nodev,fsname=portal,auto_unmount,subtype=portal -- /run/user/1000/doc
linux       4313    3902  0 14:53 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto user
```

Here is `systemctl status` output: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/XB5wncJMz5/

```
linux@dell ~> cat /etc/passwd | grep -E '^oracle|^root'
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
oracle:x:1001:1001::/home/oracle:/bin/bash
```

```
● dell
    State: degraded
     Jobs: 0 queued
   Failed: 2 units
    Since: Fri 2023-11-17 14:40:52 +0330; 4min 5s ago
   CGroup: /
           ├─user.slice 
           │ ├─user-1001.slice 
           │ │ ├─session-c4.scope 
           │ │ │ ├─2412 xe_pmon_XE
           │ │ │ ├─2415 xe_psp0_XE
           │ │ │ ├─2417 xe_vktm_XE
           │ │ │ ├─2421 xe_gen0_XE
           │ │ │ ├─2423 xe_diag_XE
           │ │ │ ├─2425 xe_dbrm_XE
           │ │ │ ├─2427 xe_dia0_XE
           │ │ │ ├─2429 xe_mman_XE
           │ │ │ ├─2431 xe_dbw0_XE
           │ │ │ ├─2433 xe_lgwr_XE
           │ │ │ ├─2435 xe_ckpt_XE
           │ │ │ ├─2437 xe_smon_XE
           │ │ │ ├─2439 xe_reco_XE
           │ │ │ ├─2441 xe_mmon_XE
           │ │ │ ├─2443 xe_mmnl_XE
           │ │ │ ├─2445 xe_d000_XE
           │ │ │ ├─2447 xe_s000_XE
           │ │ │ ├─2449 xe_s001_XE
           │ │ │ ├─2451 xe_s002_XE
           │ │ │ ├─2453 xe_s003_XE
           │ │ │ ├─2634 xe_vkrm_XE
           │ │ │ ├─2650 xe_qmnc_XE
           │ │ │ ├─2668 xe_cjq0_XE
           │ │ │ ├─2682 xe_q000_XE
           │ │ │ └─2684 xe_q001_XE
           │ │ ├─session-c1.scope 
           │ │ │ └─1514 /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/tnslsnr LISTENER -inherit
           │ │ └─user@1001.service 
           │ │   ├─session.slice 
           │ │   │ ├─pipewire-media-session.service 
           │ │   │ │ └─991 /usr/bin/pipewire-media-session
           │ │   │ └─pipewire.service 
           │ │   │   └─990 /usr/bin/pipewire
           │ │   ├─background.slice 
           │ │   │ └─tracker-miner-fs-3.service 
           │ │   │   └─1056 /usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs-3
           │ │   ├─app.slice 
           │ │   │ ├─gvfs-goa-volume-monitor.service 
           │ │   │ │ └─1089 /usr/libexec/gvfs-goa-volume-monitor
           │ │   │ ├─gvfs-daemon.service 
           │ │   │ │ ├─1023 /usr/libexec/gvfsd
           │ │   │ │ └─1029 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1001/gvfs -f
           │ │   │ ├─gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor.service 
           │ │   │ │ └─1078 /usr/libexec/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
           │ │   │ ├─gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service 
           │ │   │ │ └─1108 /usr/libexec/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
           │ │   │ ├─dbus.service 
           │ │   │ │ ├─1003 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
           │ │   │ │ ├─1093 /usr/libexec/goa-daemon
           │ │   │ │ └─1106 /usr/libexec/goa-identity-service
           │ │   │ ├─gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor.service 
           │ │   │ │ └─1122 /usr/libexec/gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor
           │ │   │ └─gvfs-afc-volume-monitor.service 
           │ │   │   └─1115 /usr/libexec/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
           │ │   └─init.scope 
           │ │     ├─940 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
           │ │     └─952 (sd-pam)
           │ └─user-1000.slice 
           │   ├─user@1000.service 
           │   │ ├─session.slice 
           │   │ │ ├─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─1878 /usr/libexec/gsd-media-keys
           │   │ │ ├─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─1898 /usr/libexec/gsd-smartcard
           │   │ │ ├─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Datetime.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─1872 /usr/libexec/gsd-datetime
           │   │ │ ├─xdg-document-portal.service 
           │   │ │ │ ├─1842 /usr/libexec/xdg-document-portal
           │   │ │ │ └─1847 fusermount3 -o rw,nosuid,nodev,fsname=portal,auto_unmount,subtype=portal -- /run/user/1000/doc
           │   │ │ ├─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─1875 /usr/libexec/gsd-housekeeping
           │   │ │ ├─org.gnome.Shell@x11.service 
           │   │ │ │ ├─1748 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
           │   │ │ │ └─2200 gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com/ding.js -E -P /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com -M 0 -D 0:0:1366:768:1:27:70:0:0:0
           │   │ │ ├─xdg-desktop-portal.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─1838 /usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal
           │   │ │ ├─org.freedesktop.IBus.session.GNOME.service 
           │   │ │ │ ├─1867 sh -c /usr/bin/ibus-daemon --panel disable $([ "$XDG_SESSION_TYPE" = "x11" ] && echo "--xim")
           │   │ │ │ ├─1873 /usr/bin/ibus-daemon --panel disable --xim
           │   │ │ │ ├─1961 /usr/libexec/ibus-memconf
           │   │ │ │ ├─1963 /usr/libexec/ibus-extension-gtk3
           │   │ │ │ ├─1969 /usr/libexec/ibus-x11 --kill-daemon
           │   │ │ │ └─2084 /usr/libexec/ibus-engine-simple
           │   │ │ ├─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─1876 /usr/libexec/gsd-keyboard
           │   │ │ ├─pipewire-media-session.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─1541 /usr/bin/pipewire-media-session
           │   │ │ ├─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.A11ySettings.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─1868 /usr/libexec/gsd-a11y-settings
           │   │ │ ├─pulseaudio.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─1542 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal
           │   │ │ ├─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─1908 /usr/libexec/gsd-wacom
           │   │ │ ├─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─1896 /usr/libexec/gsd-sharing
           │   │ │ ├─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─1870 /usr/libexec/gsd-color
           │   │ │ ├─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─1887 /usr/libexec/gsd-screensaver-proxy
           │   │ │ ├─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications.service 
           │   │ │ │ ├─1882 /usr/libexec/gsd-print-notifications
           │   │ │ │ └─1946 /usr/libexec/gsd-printer
           │   │ │ ├─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─1880 /usr/libexec/gsd-power
           │   │ │ ├─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─1914 /usr/libexec/gsd-xsettings
           │   │ │ ├─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─1902 /usr/libexec/gsd-sound
           │   │ │ ├─pipewire.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─1540 /usr/bin/pipewire
           │   │ │ └─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill.service 
           │   │ │   └─1886 /usr/libexec/gsd-rfkill
           │   │ ├─background.slice 
           │   │ │ └─tracker-miner-fs-3.service 
           │   │ │   └─1626 /usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs-3
           │   │ ├─app.slice 
           │   │ │ ├─gvfs-goa-volume-monitor.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─1680 /usr/libexec/gvfs-goa-volume-monitor
           │   │ │ ├─app-gnome-update\x2dnotifier-3094.scope 
           │   │ │ │ └─3094 update-notifier
           │   │ │ ├─xdg-permission-store.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─1771 /usr/libexec/xdg-permission-store
           │   │ │ ├─app-gnome-gnome\x2dsoftware\x2dservice-1948.scope 
           │   │ │ │ └─1948 /usr/bin/gnome-software --gapplication-service
           │   │ │ ├─app-gnome-google\x2dchrome-3133.scope 
           │   │ │ │ ├─3133 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
           │   │ │ │ ├─3138 cat
           │   │ │ │ ├─3139 cat
           │   │ │ │ ├─3142 /opt/google/chrome/chrome_crashpad_handler --monitor-self --monitor-self-annotation=ptype=crashpad-handler --database=/home/linux/.config/google-chrome/Crash Reports --metrics-dir=/home/linux/.config/google-chrome --url=https://clients2.google.com/cr/report --annotation=channel= --annotation=lsb-release=Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS --annotation=plat=Linux --annotation=prod=Chrome_Linux --annotation=ver=119.0.6045.159 --initial-client-fd=5 --shared-client-connection
           │   │ │ │ ├─3144 /opt/google/chrome/chrome_crashpad_handler --no-periodic-tasks --monitor-self-annotation=ptype=crashpad-handler --database=/home/linux/.config/google-chrome/Crash Reports --url=https://clients2.google.com/cr/report --annotation=channel= --annotation=lsb-release=Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS --annotation=plat=Linux --annotation=prod=Chrome_Linux --annotation=ver=119.0.6045.159 --initial-client-fd=4 --shared-client-connection
           │   │ │ │ ├─3150 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=zygote --no-zygote-sandbox --crashpad-handler-pid=3142 --enable-crash-reporter=64023579-3371-43d4-982b-415d61c57810, --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable
           │   │ │ │ ├─3151 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=zygote --crashpad-handler-pid=3142 --enable-crash-reporter=64023579-3371-43d4-982b-415d61c57810, --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable
           │   │ │ │ ├─3152 /opt/google/chrome/nacl_helper
           │   │ │ │ ├─3155 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=zygote --crashpad-handler-pid=3142 --enable-crash-reporter=64023579-3371-43d4-982b-415d61c57810, --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable
           │   │ │ │ ├─3180 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=gpu-process --crashpad-handler-pid=3142 --enable-crash-reporter=64023579-3371-43d4-982b-415d61c57810, --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable --gpu-preferences=WAAAAAAAAAAgAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAA4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAGAAAAAAAAAAYAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAAIAAAAAAAAAA== --use-gl=angle --use-angle=swiftshader-webgl --shared-files --field-trial-handle=0,i,3977374580890560187,1171444396577728651,262144
           │   │ │ │ ├─3181 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=utility --utility-sub-type=network.mojom.NetworkService --lang=en-US --service-sandbox-type=none --crashpad-handler-pid=3142 --enable-crash-reporter=64023579-3371-43d4-982b-415d61c57810, --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100 --field-trial-handle=0,i,3977374580890560187,1171444396577728651,262144
           │   │ │ │ ├─3192 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=utility --utility-sub-type=storage.mojom.StorageService --lang=en-US --service-sandbox-type=utility --crashpad-handler-pid=3142 --enable-crash-reporter=64023579-3371-43d4-982b-415d61c57810, --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100 --field-trial-handle=0,i,3977374580890560187,1171444396577728651,262144
           │   │ │ │ ├─3279 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --crashpad-handler-pid=3142 --enable-crash-reporter=64023579-3371-43d4-982b-415d61c57810, --extension-process --disable-nacl --origin-trial-disabled-features=WebGPU --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable --disable-gpu-compositing --lang=en-US --num-raster-threads=2 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=8 --time-ticks-at-unix-epoch=-1700219450235456 --launch-time-ticks=87985929 --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100 --field-trial-handle=0,i,3977374580890560187,1171444396577728651,262144
           │   │ │ │ ├─3340 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --crashpad-handler-pid=3142 --enable-crash-reporter=64023579-3371-43d4-982b-415d61c57810, --extension-process --disable-nacl --origin-trial-disabled-features=WebGPU --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable --disable-gpu-compositing --lang=en-US --num-raster-threads=2 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=9 --time-ticks-at-unix-epoch=-1700219450235456 --launch-time-ticks=88052691 --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100 --field-trial-handle=0,i,3977374580890560187,1171444396577728651,262144
           │   │ │ │ ├─3514 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --crashpad-handler-pid=3142 --enable-crash-reporter=64023579-3371-43d4-982b-415d61c57810, --disable-nacl --origin-trial-disabled-features=WebGPU --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable --disable-gpu-compositing --lang=en-US --num-raster-threads=2 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=14 --time-ticks-at-unix-epoch=-1700219450235456 --launch-time-ticks=103323163 --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100 --field-trial-handle=0,i,3977374580890560187,1171444396577728651,262144
           │   │ │ │ ├─3803 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --crashpad-handler-pid=3142 --enable-crash-reporter=64023579-3371-43d4-982b-415d61c57810, --disable-nacl --origin-trial-disabled-features=WebGPU --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable --disable-gpu-compositing --lang=en-US --num-raster-threads=2 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=23 --time-ticks-at-unix-epoch=-1700219450235456 --launch-time-ticks=142376761 --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100 --field-trial-handle=0,i,3977374580890560187,1171444396577728651,262144
           │   │ │ │ ├─3812 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --crashpad-handler-pid=3142 --enable-crash-reporter=64023579-3371-43d4-982b-415d61c57810, --disable-nacl --origin-trial-disabled-features=WebGPU --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable --disable-gpu-compositing --lang=en-US --num-raster-threads=2 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=24 --time-ticks-at-unix-epoch=-1700219450235456 --launch-time-ticks=142668095 --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100 --field-trial-handle=0,i,3977374580890560187,1171444396577728651,262144
           │   │ │ │ ├─3823 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=utility --utility-sub-type=data_decoder.mojom.DataDecoderService --lang=en-US --service-sandbox-type=service --crashpad-handler-pid=3142 --enable-crash-reporter=64023579-3371-43d4-982b-415d61c57810, --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100 --field-trial-handle=0,i,3977374580890560187,1171444396577728651,262144
           │   │ │ │ └─3861 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --crashpad-handler-pid=3142 --enable-crash-reporter=64023579-3371-43d4-982b-415d61c57810, --disable-nacl --origin-trial-disabled-features=WebGPU --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable --disable-gpu-compositing --lang=en-US --num-raster-threads=2 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=28 --time-ticks-at-unix-epoch=-1700219450235456 --launch-time-ticks=155415510 --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100 --field-trial-handle=0,i,3977374580890560187,1171444396577728651,262144
           │   │ │ ├─evolution-calendar-factory.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─1792 /usr/libexec/evolution-calendar-factory
           │   │ │ ├─app-gnome-org.gnome.Evolution\x2dalarm\x2dnotify-1964.scope 
           │   │ │ │ └─1964 /usr/libexec/evolution-data-server/evolution-alarm-notify
           │   │ │ ├─xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─1850 /usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal-gnome
           │   │ │ ├─dconf.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─1796 /usr/libexec/dconf-service
           │   │ │ ├─app-gnome\x2dsession\x2dmanager.slice 
           │   │ │ │ └─gnome-session-manager@ubuntu.service 
           │   │ │ │   └─1720 /usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --systemd-service --session=ubuntu
           │   │ │ ├─gvfs-daemon.service 
           │   │ │ │ ├─1561 /usr/libexec/gvfsd
           │   │ │ │ ├─1566 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs -f
           │   │ │ │ └─1828 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-trash --spawner :1.5 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/0
           │   │ │ ├─evolution-source-registry.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─1782 /usr/libexec/evolution-source-registry
           │   │ │ ├─gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─1668 /usr/libexec/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
           │   │ │ ├─ssh-agent.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─1705 ssh-agent -D -a /run/user/1000/openssh_agent
           │   │ │ ├─app-org.gnome.Terminal.slice 
           │   │ │ │ ├─vte-spawn-7b6b4236-fb4d-47b0-be4f-5b602e80b8f9.scope 
           │   │ │ │ │ ├─3902 bash
           │   │ │ │ │ ├─3909 fish
           │   │ │ │ │ └─3973 systemctl status
           │   │ │ │ └─gnome-terminal-server.service 
           │   │ │ │   └─3879 /usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server
           │   │ │ ├─app-gnome-org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.DiskUtilityNotify-1968.scope 
           │   │ │ │ └─1968 /usr/libexec/gsd-disk-utility-notify
           │   │ │ ├─app-gnome-org.gnome.DejaDup.Monitor-3829.scope 
           │   │ │ │ └─3829 /usr/libexec/deja-dup/deja-dup-monitor
           │   │ │ ├─gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─1714 /usr/libexec/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
           │   │ │ ├─gnome-session-monitor.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─1701 /usr/libexec/gnome-session-ctl --monitor
           │   │ │ ├─app-gnome-x\x2dterminal\x2demulator-3873.scope 
           │   │ │ │ ├─3873 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/gnome-terminal --wait
           │   │ │ │ └─3876 /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real --wait
           │   │ │ ├─xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─2104 /usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
           │   │ │ ├─at-spi-dbus-bus.service 
           │   │ │ │ ├─1667 /usr/libexec/at-spi-bus-launcher
           │   │ │ │ ├─1676 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/defaults/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 11 --address=unix:path=/run/user/1000/at-spi/bus_0
           │   │ │ │ └─1855 /usr/libexec/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-session
           │   │ │ ├─gvfs-metadata.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─2197 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-metadata
           │   │ │ ├─dbus.service 
           │   │ │ │ ├─1550 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
           │   │ │ │ ├─1684 /usr/libexec/goa-daemon
           │   │ │ │ ├─1697 /usr/libexec/goa-identity-service
           │   │ │ │ ├─1773 /usr/libexec/gnome-shell-calendar-server
           │   │ │ │ ├─1852 /usr/bin/gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/org.gnome.Shell.Notifications
           │   │ │ │ ├─1974 /usr/libexec/ibus-portal
           │   │ │ │ └─2063 /usr/bin/gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/org.gnome.ScreenSaver
           │   │ │ ├─evolution-addressbook-factory.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─1810 /usr/libexec/evolution-addressbook-factory
           │   │ │ ├─gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor.service 
           │   │ │ │ └─1729 /usr/libexec/gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor
           │   │ │ ├─app-gnome-indicator\x2dmessages-1954.scope 
           │   │ │ │ └─1954 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-messages/indicator-messages-service
           │   │ │ └─gvfs-afc-volume-monitor.service 
           │   │ │   └─1724 /usr/libexec/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
           │   │ └─init.scope 
           │   │   ├─1532 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
           │   │   └─1533 (sd-pam)
           │   └─session-c3.scope 
           │     ├─1329 lightdm --session-child 12 19
           │     ├─1546 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
           │     └─1551 /usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --session=ubuntu
           ├─init.scope 
           │ └─1 /sbin/init splash
           └─system.slice 
             ├─irqbalance.service 
             │ └─458 /usr/sbin/irqbalance --foreground
             ├─apache2.service 
             │ ├─715 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             │ ├─730 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             │ ├─732 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             │ ├─736 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             │ ├─737 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             │ └─738 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─packagekit.service 
             │ └─1813 /usr/libexec/packagekitd
             ├─systemd-udevd.service 
             │ └─313 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
             ├─cron.service 
             │ └─485 /usr/sbin/cron -f -P
             ├─thermald.service 
             │ └─504 /usr/sbin/thermald --systemd --dbus-enable --adaptive
             ├─polkit.service 
             │ └─462 /usr/libexec/polkitd --no-debug
             ├─networkd-dispatcher.service 
             │ └─459 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher --run-startup-triggers
             ├─rtkit-daemon.service 
             │ └─998 /usr/libexec/rtkit-daemon
             ├─bluetooth.service 
             │ └─961 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
             ├─accounts-daemon.service 
             │ └─481 /usr/libexec/accounts-daemon
             ├─wpa_supplicant.service 
             │ └─509 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant
             ├─lightdm.service 
             │ ├─925 /usr/sbin/lightdm
             │ └─970 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
             ├─ModemManager.service 
             │ └─610 /usr/sbin/ModemManager
             ├─systemd-journald.service 
             │ └─268 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
             ├─winbind.service 
             │ ├─703 /usr/sbin/winbindd --foreground --no-process-group
             │ └─775 winbindd: domain child [DELL]
             ├─power-profiles-daemon.service 
             │ └─474 /usr/libexec/power-profiles-daemon
             ├─unattended-upgrades.service 
             │ └─701 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrade-shutdown --wait-for-signal
             ├─fwupd.service 
             │ └─2042 /usr/libexec/fwupd/fwupd
             ├─colord.service 
             │ └─913 /usr/libexec/colord
             ├─NetworkManager.service 
             │ └─440 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
             ├─switcheroo-control.service 
             │ └─487 /usr/libexec/switcheroo-control
             ├─mysql.service 
             │ └─959 /usr/sbin/mysqld
             ├─rsyslog.service 
             │ └─479 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n -iNONE
             ├─kerneloops.service 
             │ ├─1406 /usr/sbin/kerneloops --test
             │ └─1414 /usr/sbin/kerneloops
             ├─cups-browsed.service 
             │ └─1376 /usr/sbin/cups-browsed
             ├─smartmontools.service 
             │ └─480 /usr/sbin/smartd -n
             ├─cups.service 
             │ └─665 /usr/sbin/cupsd -l
             ├─upower.service 
             │ └─1127 /usr/libexec/upowerd
             ├─system-tor.slice 
             │ └─tor@default.service 
             │   └─784 /usr/bin/tor --defaults-torrc /usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc -f /etc/tor/torrc --RunAsDaemon 0
             ├─systemd-oomd.service 
             │ └─390 /lib/systemd/systemd-oomd
             ├─systemd-resolved.service 
             │ └─391 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved
             ├─udisks2.service 
             │ └─506 /usr/libexec/udisks2/udisksd
             ├─acpid.service 
             │ └─419 /usr/sbin/acpid
             ├─tomcat.service 
             │ └─799 /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/latest/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -classpath /opt/tomcat/latest/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/latest/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat/latest -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat/latest -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/latest/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
             ├─dbus.service 
             │ └─439 @dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
             ├─systemd-timesyncd.service 
             │ └─392 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
             ├─system-getty.slice 
             │ └─getty@tty1.service 
             │   └─975 /sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --noclear tty1 linux
             ├─avahi-daemon.service 
             │ ├─433 avahi-daemon: running [dell.local]
             │ └─537 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
             └─systemd-logind.service 
               └─502 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
```

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Only one user `linux` appears to be logged-in via a graphical user session ... What other users do you mean? and how do you know?

Comment: user oracle and root is alsow logged in.

Comment: You seem to have logged-in via SSH as well with your own user `linux` with some command like `ssh localhost` or other SSH based tools and that seems to be why you get the warning message "*other users are logged in `linux`*" ... Does this ring a bell?

Comment: `oracl` and `root` seem to be owners of some processes that are currently being run on your system and no other sign of them or any other user than you being actually logged-in.

Comment: It looks like you are running an Oracle DB listener as a systemd user service?

Comment: ... please [edit] your question to include the output of `systemd-inhibit --list`

Comment: @steeldriver You seem to be suspicious of an inhibitor placed by Oracle DB or some other app … While that might be true, I wonder why the message they set will read "other users are logged in".

Comment: @Raffa I *think* it's just different definitions of "logged in" - `w` is old school, and only knows about utmp entries - I suspect the display manager is writing a utmp entry for the user 1000 regular GUI session, but the oracle user slice is only tracked by systemd-logind

Answer (score 0):

As I can see at pastebin one user was connected via tty1.

```
             │   └─975 /sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --noclear tty1 linux
```